# Converting an UnsafePointer with length to a Swift Array type

Tags: c, arrays, swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm looking for the simplest ways to achieve reasonable C interoperability in Swift, and my current block is converting an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` (which was a `const char *`), into an `[Int8]` array.

Currently, I have a naïve algorithm that can take an `UnsafePointer` and a number of bytes and converts it to an array, element by element:

```
func convert(length: Int, data: UnsafePointer<Int8>) {

    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: length);
    var arr: [Int8] = [Int8]()
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr.append(buffer[i])
    }
}
```

The loop itself can be sped up by using `arr.reserveCapacity(length)`, however that does not remove the issue of the loop itself.

I'm aware of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25042695/1618592) which covers how to convert `UnsafePointer<Int8>`to `String`, however `String` is a different beast entirely to `[T]`. Is there a convenient Swift way of copying length bytes from an `UnsafePointer<T>` into a `[T]`? I'd prefer pure Swift methods, without passing through `NSData` or similar. If the above algorithm is really the only way to do it, I'm happy to stick with that.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can simply initialize a Swift `Array` from an `UnsafeBufferPointer`:

```
func convert(length: Int, data: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> [Int8] {

    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: length);
    return Array(buffer)
}
```

This creates an array of the needed size and copies the data.

Or as a generic function:

```
func convert<T>(count: Int, data: UnsafePointer<T>) -> [T] {

    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: count);
    return Array(buffer) 
}
```

where `length` is the number of *items* that the pointer points to.

If you have a `UInt8` pointer but want to create an `[T]` array from 
the pointed-to data, then this is a possible solution:

```
// Swift 2:
func convert<T>(length: Int, data: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, _: T.Type) -> [T] {

    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer<T>(start: UnsafePointer(data), count: length/strideof(T));
    return Array(buffer) 
}

// Swift 3:
func convert<T>(length: Int, data: UnsafePointer<UInt8>, _: T.Type) -> [T] {
    let numItems = length/MemoryLayout<T>.stride
    let buffer = data.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: numItems) {
        UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: numItems)
    }
    return Array(buffer) 
}
```

where `length` now is the number of *bytes*. Example:

```
let arr  = convert(12, data: ptr, Float.self)
```

would create an array of 3 `Float`s from the 12 bytes pointed to by `ptr`.

Comment: Does this cause a memory leak? I can't find any indication that `UnsafeBufferPointer` will free its memory

Comment: @AMomchilov: `UnsafeBufferPointer` is just a pointer, it does not allocate memory, so there is nothing to free. The `Array` is then managed by Swift.

Comment: Yes, but the pointer passed into `convert` has to be freed, right? That should be made explicit, IMO

Comment: @AMomchilov: You are right, if the memory has been allocated then it must be freed eventually. But we don't know where that pointer comes from, it could point to static memory. As I see it, that is independent of the `convert` function.

Comment: In Swift 3, the `let buffer` line should be `let buffer = data.withMemoryRebound(to: T.self, capacity: 1) {UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: length/MemoryLayout<T>.stride)}`

Comment: @kabiroberai: Thanks, updated! (The capacity should be the number of target items as well.)

Comment: @MartinR welcome  may I ask though, why does `capacity` need to be the number of items? It seems to work even when capacity is set to 1 (since `$0` only refers to the *start* and not the entire data).

Comment: @kabiroberai: Well, that is how I understand the description *"Rebinds memory at self to type T with capacity to hold count adjacent T values while executing the body closure. "*. I must admit that I don't know what the consequences of a different value would be.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension NSData {

    public func convertToBytes() -> [UInt8] {
        let count = self.length / sizeof(UInt8)
        var bytesArray = [UInt8](count: count, repeatedValue: 0)
        self.getBytes(&bytesArray, length:count * sizeof(UInt8))
        return bytesArray
    }
}
```

You can convert row data to byts (Uint8)

Copy Extension and use it..

Comment: This is insanely helpful. My C <-> Swift interop anxiety is just melting away.

Comment: Nice to hear that ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Array init function:

```swift
init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: Int, initializingWith initializer: (inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>, inout Int) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

First convert the unsafeRawPointer to unsafePointer if needed
Then convert the pointer to a buffer pointer, and finally the buffer pointer to an array.

Example, assuming you have an unsafeRawPointer (`dataPtr`) and its size (`dataSize`)

```swift
let numberOfItems = dataSize / MemoryLayout<MyClass>.stride

let myArray = dataPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: MyClass.self,
                                        capacity: numberOfItems) { typedPtr in
    // Convert pointer to buffer pointer to access buffer via indices
    let bufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: typedPtr, count: numberOfItems)
    // Construct array
    return [MyClass](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: numberOfItems) { arrayBuffer, count in
        count = numberOfItems
        for i in 0..<count {
            arrayBuffer[i] = bufferPointer[i]
        }
    }
}
```