# Interoperating with C pointer to an Int array in Swift

Tags: swift

I've got a legacy codebase with this function:

```
-(void)foo: (int *)buffer {
  myArray[0] = buffer[0];
  myArray[1] = buffer[1];
  myArray[2] = buffer[2];
  myArray[3] = buffer[3];
}
```

In Swift, this method is written as the following:

```
func foo(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
}
```

The `int` pointer is now considered an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>`. I'm having trouble accessing the subscripts of `buffer` in Swift; i.e. I cannot call `buffer[0]` like this:

```
func foo(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
  myArray[0] = buffer[0] // won't compile, buffer treated as Int32
}
```

Out of desperation, even knowing that `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>` is ultimately resolved as a `Int32` type in Swift, I've tried the following:

```
guard let buffer = buffer.memory as? [Int] else { fatalError() }

guard let buffer = buffer as? [Int] else { fatalError() }

guard let buffer = buffer.memory as? [Int32] else { fatalError() }

guard let buffer = buffer as? [Int32] else { fatalError() }
```

Could someone point me to the right direction on understanding how I could access the subscript members like how the Objective-C code did?

Comment: Related: [Converting an UnsafePointer with length to a Swift Array type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606989/converting-an-unsafepointer-with-length-to-a-swift-array-type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking it:

```
class MyClass {
    var myArray = [Int32](count: 4, repeatedValue: 0)

    func foo(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
        for i in 0..<4 {
            myArray[i] = buffer[i]
        }
    }
}
```

You can change `myArray` to `[Int32]` to make it match `buffer`. Or you can cast `buffer` to `Int`:

```
myArray[i] = Int(buffer[i])
```

Comment: Thanks, I did overthink it; For future reference to others, `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>` DOES allow for subscripting.

Comment: As a side note, I'm curious why `guard let buffer = buffer.memory as? [Int32] else { fatalError() }` would fail. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: `memory` points to the first element of your array, not the array itself hence not castable

Comment: How about `guard let buffer = buffer as? [Int32] else { ... }`?

Comment: Didn't realize `UnsafeMutablePointer` was subscriptable, that's good to know. Not a fan of this approach in general, as there's a cleaner, built-in way to do this

Answer (score 3):

[`UnsafePointer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafepointer) is meant to model a single location in memory. For dealing with a buffer, use [`UnsafeBufferPointer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafebufferpointer).

`UnsafeBufferPointer` can be subscripted like an `Array`, and has bound checking (since it requires you give it a `count`).

You don't even have to do that manual conversion like in your Objective C code, you can initialize `Array` directly from `UnsafeBufferPointer`, very easily:

```
func foo(buffer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>) {
    myArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: 4))
}
```

This solution is even generic: `UnsafeBufferPointer` can infer its type from the `UnsafePointer` you give it, and pass that info along to `Array`, to make it automagically create a `[Int32]`

**Note**: Remember to deallocate your UnsafePointer!

Comment: Thanks. Really cool approach. I confirmed that this also works.

May I ask if you know of a method to safely find the `count` of the `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`?

Comment: Nope, this is too "low level" for that. The `UnsafeMutablePointer` just knows an address and a type. It has no way of knowing the length, which is why you have to supply it. If you're dealing with a C string, you can iterate to find the first `NUL` character. Other than that, there's no way to know

Comment: You can probably obtain the length from whatever source gave you the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you instead use `UnsafeBufferPointer`?

http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/UnsafeBufferPointer/